# 500 errors do not appear in the apache2 error.log on Debian9

Tags: php, debian, apache2, http-status-code-500, error-log

I am having trouble with apache2 error.log. The 500 errors are not appearing there (/var/log/apache2/error.log), I am just getting these lines every time I restart the apache2 service :

```
[Tue May 26 10:19:33.931998 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30119] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Tue May 26 10:19:33.947081 2020] [so:warn] [pid 30119] AH01574: module ssl_module is already loaded, skipping
[Tue May 26 10:19:33.968226 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30119] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.0.2u configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue May 26 10:19:33.968246 2020] [core:notice] [pid 30119] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

I put error_reporting = **E_ALL**, display_errors = **On**, display_startup_errors = **On**, log_errors = **On** in the **/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini** AND **/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini**.

I don't even get the errors on the browser, I am just receiving a message in the inspector "**500 Internal Servor Error**".

What else should I configure to make them appear in the error.log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I missed one thing, such the biggest thing.

I had to change the LogLevel from **warn** to **debug** in apache2.conf file (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf) and now it works !